# Tables behind MB1A transaction?

Tags: sap-erp

I would like to access(see) table(s) which lays behind MB1A transaction, can anyone with more experience can tell what is the *exact name* of table(s)?

Many thanks in advance!

Best regards,
Adi

Answer (score 2):

I can't, but I can tell you how you can find out for yourself: Start transaction ST05 and activate the SQL trace. Then do whatever you want to examine, switch the trace off again and take your time examining it.

Answer (score 0):

Another convenient way of finding this data is using the “new” transaction SAT. This is an enhanced version of SE30 and is available from Netweaver 7.0, EhP2

- Run Transaction SAT - Enter the required transaction and press Execute
  [image: Transaction SAT]
- Execute the transaction as per usual, and exit when you're done
- Click on "DB Tables" and you will see all tables that was accessed during your trace
  [image]